# spring mvc4 initBinder model

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, model, controller

I'm need to access some model info in a custom editor. I've tried to use ModelMap as an initBinder params but I obtain a deny error on runtime.
Any idea?

```
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(MyData.class, new MyCustomEditor(model));
}
```

TIA
Ice72

Answer (score 0):

@InitBinder just register the Editors and Validators, the ModelMap which mapping the HTML<form> will be created after the initBinder, before the @RequestMapping method.

You can use the service in you CustomEditor, and format the fields of your ModelMap which will be created.

```
public class MyCustomEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private YourService service;

    public MyCustomEditor(YourService service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text){
        // TODO service can work here
        setValue(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText(){
        // TODO service can work here
        return (String) getValue();
    }

}
```

---

```
@Resource
YourService yourService;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.registerCustomEditor(MyData.class, "fieldInMyData", new MyCustomEditor(yourService));
}
```